# How to scan through a string, identify and convert to NSURL

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I would like to go through a string and identify if in that string there is a URL. If there is, I would like to format it in such a way that the user can tap on the URL.

Please note that the strings are not static or always the same. The strings are JSON data that belong to comments and post in an app's feed.

My first idea was to use a regEx expression and create a function that scans through a string, identifies if there is a match for `http://` or `https://`etc. and then turn that range of the string into an `NSURL`.

Any other ideas, advices, solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSDataDetector`. Nice article about it: http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/

Comment: +1 for `NSDataDetector`. In particular note the `UIDataDetectorTypes` and their use in a `UITextView`, where the link will be made clickable automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander, I will go for the `NSDataDetector` solution!

Comment: BTW any hints on how to setup a filter so `NSDataDector` **only** converts one specific domain i.e. `www.enrq.co` and ignores all the others?

Comment: You can get `NSURL` from `NSDataDetector` and then check, if this url belongs to your domain (by checking `host` property)

Answer (score 0):

The `NSDataDetector` class is a specialized subclass of `NSRegularExpression` designed to match natural language text for predefined data patterns.

Currently the `NSDataDetector` class can match dates, addresses, links, phone numbers and transit information.

```
NSError *error = nil;
   NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink|NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
                                                              error:&error];
```

Determine the number of matches within a range of a string using the NSRegularExpression method numberOfMatchesInString:options:range:.

```
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [detector numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                          options:0
                                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Check more at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/

OR

If you have UITextView or UIWebView you can Detect link by simply setting `dataDetectorTypes` Property.

For UITextView:

```
TextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

For UIWebView:

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

For more information check : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1495/_index.html

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak, also for the links.